# How to read Powershell variable inside Dockerfile?

Tags: powershell, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop, docker

I'm building **Docker Desktop for Windows** image.
I try to pass a variable to a Powershell command, but it does not work.

#### Dockerfile

```
# escape=`
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

RUN $someVar="2.60.3" ; echo $someVar
```

#### Docker build

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
 ---> 2c42a1b4dea8
Step 2/3 : SHELL powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ebd40122e316
Step 3/3 : RUN $someVar="2.60.3" ; echo $someVar
 ---> Running in dd28b74bdbda
 ---> 94e17242f6da
Removing intermediate container dd28b74bdbda
Successfully built 94e17242f6da
Successfully tagged secrets:latest
```

#### Exprected result

I can workaround this by using ENV variable and, possibly, a multistage build to avoid keeping this variable:

```
# escape=`
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

ENV someVar="2.60.3" 
RUN echo $env:someVar

Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/4 : FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
 ---> 2c42a1b4dea8
Step 2/4 : SHELL powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ebd40122e316
Step 3/4 : ENV someVar "2.60.3"
 ---> Running in 8ac10815ff6d
 ---> 9073ec3256e0
Removing intermediate container 8ac10815ff6d
Step 4/4 : RUN echo $env:someVar
 ---> Running in 43a41df36f92
2.60.3
 ---> 09e48901bea9
Removing intermediate container 43a41df36f92
Successfully built 09e48901bea9
Successfully tagged secrets:latest
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but i suspect this is due to how Docker [handles double-quotes](https://github.com/StefanScherer/dockerfiles-windows/tree/master/quotes) with the `RUN` command. Try escaping them like so: `\"`.

Comment: @Persistent13 Indeed, that was the case! Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Double-quotes need to be [escaped](https://github.com/StefanScherer/dockerfiles-windows/tree/master/quotes) for them to work as expected, like so `someVar=\"2.60.3\"`.